# Make Page Scrolling Higher than the bottom of the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I understand my title isn't very descriptive as its hard to explain so I will try and give as much detail I can into my problem.

[image]

In the image you can see that the text from the results goes over the images, I want the page to scroll before the 3 images at the bottom of the window so the text does not go underneath and is controlled by a vertical scroll bar.

The text overlaps the images on the bottom of the window, here is what I want, I want the page to scroll from just before these images at the bottom so the content doesn't go under or overlap the images at the bottom, these images at the bottom of the window are fixed to the bottom of the browsers page, so I need the content to scroll just before the images on different types of browsers, so how would I change the size of the content so its scrolls before the images?

I just cannot seem to think of a logical fix for this issue, and I have not been able to find a solution for this problem (or one closely related to it) on the internet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. There are many people here willing to help, but please make sure you've showed what you've tried, what didn't work, and the context of your question. Please make sure you've read [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and then edit your question to better attract people's expenditure of time and effort.If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing any code for this problem, my only suggestion is to add a margin-bottom to the element surrounding the text that is overlapping the image.  This bottom margin should be the same height as the images you have fixed to the bottom of the page (or maybe 10 or 20 pixels more to get some padding between the text and the images).

Here is an example (assuming your images are 75px in height):

HTML:

```
<div id="result-wrapper">
   <!-- all of your text elements here -->
</div>

<div id="fixed-images">
   <!-- your images at the bottom of the page -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#result-wrapper {
    margin-bottom:90px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, seems to simple now you've said it, that solution fixed the problem, thanks again!

Comment: If the images are fixed to the bottom of the browser screen, wouldn't the result-wrapper still overlap the fixed images if the result list was long enough?

Comment: I wouldn't think so.  As long as the margin-bottom covers the height of the images, the scrolling effect should make it appear as if the the result list was behind the images.